# Error obtaining the filesystem using unsquash

Tags: binary, squashfs

I was following this tutorial [Reverse Engineering TP-Link TL-WA901ND firmware and obtaining the filesystem](https://thunderysteak.github.io/tl-wa901nd-basic-re) and even following the step by step you fall into an error

```
unsquashfs TP_FS
FATAL ERROR: Can't find a valid SQUASHFS superblock on TP_FS
```

My follows

```
binwalk TP_LINK.bin

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             TP-Link firmware header, firmware version: 0.0.3, image version: "", product ID: 0x0, product version: 151060482, kernel load address: 0x0, kernel entry point: 0x80002000, kernel offset: 3932160, kernel length: 512, rootfs offset: 827293, rootfs length: 1048576, bootloader offset: 2883584, bootloader length: 0
512           0x200           gzip compressed data, has original file name: "vmlinux.bin", from Unix, last modified: 2013-01-31 06:51:44
1048576       0x100000        Squashfs filesystem, big endian, lzma signature, version 3.1, size: 1790701 bytes, 353 inodes, blocksize: 65536 bytes, created: 2013-01-31 06:56:49


dd if=TP_LINK.bin skip=1048576 bs=1 of=TP_FS
2883584+0 records in
2883584+0 records out
2883584 bytes (2.9 MB, 2.8 MiB) copied, 13.9301 s, 207 kB/s


file TP_FS
TP_FS: data
```

Comment: sry, I already update

Comment: It looks like it uses nonstandard file magic `qshs`, similar to what's described here [unsquashfs fails](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162926/unsquashfs-fails)

Comment: hmm so, Should the `file` command display, in addition to the data type, how it is compressed?

Comment: Yes, the `file` command should say something like `filesystem.squashfs: Squashfs filesystem, big endian, version 3.1, lzma compressed, 1790701 bytes, 353 inodes, blocksize: 65536 bytes, created: Thu Jan 31 06:56:49 2013` if it recognizes the header. Perhaps the author of your linked tutorial is using a patched version of `unsquashfs` that recognizes the modified format? (that's what `sasquach` is btw).

Comment: That's worked man, thanks!